# Retrieving values from an SQLite database using a switch statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My problem is my switch statement is not working correctly as it is not allowing for me to retrieve the data from my sqlite database correctly using a bundle extra.

My aim is if you click the 'Topic1' or 'Topic2' buttons it puts a relevant value into the bundle extra in the tutorialpage.java and using that value in the quizactivity.java it loads questions with the specific value of qid's from the sqlite database, so topic1 will have the questions with qid of 1-3 and topic2 will have the qid of 4-5.

Currently without the switch statement, using only the code in case 1 on its own, this program will retrieve the questions up to what ever value is given, however in this program it doesn't do this properly, it currently only shows question 1 on both quizzes. The next question button does not work, it acts as if there is no onclick method on it when it should go to the next question in the selected range.

As you can see from some commented out sections I get nullpointerexceptions as well.

My files are as follows:

tutorialpage.java, the tutorial page xml has two buttons with id's of Topic1 and Topic2, this is a switch statement to put an intent extra for which button is clicked.

```
    public void GotoTheQuizButton (View view) {
        Intent intentStart = new Intent(tutorialpage.this, QuizActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.Topic1:
             /*   intentStart.putExtra(Quiz_NUMBER, 1);*/
                bundle.putInt(Quiz_NUMBER, 1);
                intentStart.putExtras(bundle);
                break;
            case R.id.Topic2:
         /*       intentStart.putExtra(Quiz_NUMBER, 2);*/
                bundle.putInt(Quiz_NUMBER, 2);
                intentStart.putExtras(bundle);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intentStart);
    }
}
```

QuizActivity.java, this is the file where the Switch statement is not retrieving the intent extra properly so it only retrieves the first question for some reason.

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    List<Question> quesList;
    int score=0;
    int qid=0;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
    Button butNext;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }
        private void setQuestionView()
    {
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        rda.setText(currentQ.getAnsA());
        rdb.setText(currentQ.getAnsB());
        rdc.setText(currentQ.getAnsC());
        qid++;
    }
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial_quiz);

        DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
        quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        setQuestionView();



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        int Quiz = intent.getIntExtra(tutorialpage.Quiz_NUMBER, 0);
/*
 null pointer exception
 int Quiz = intent.getStringExtra(tutorialpage.Quiz_NUMBER, 0);
                int Quiz = extras.getInt(tutorialpage.Quiz_NUMBER);*/


/*   Check the value being passed to the switch
     Toast login = Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Welcome " + Quiz, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        login.show();*/


        switch(Quiz ) {
            case 1:
                Toast login = Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Welcome " + Quiz, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                login.show();

                butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                        RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                        Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
                        if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
                        { score++;  Log.d("score", "Your score" + score); }

                           while (qid < 3){ currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                            setQuestionView();
                               Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                               Bundle b = new Bundle();
                               b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                               intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                               startActivity(intent);
                               }
                                finish();
                    }
                });
                break;


            case 2:
                butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                        RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                        Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
                        if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
                            score++;
                            Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
                        }

                        while (qid >= 4 && qid <= 5) {
                            currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
                            setQuestionView();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                            intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                break;
        }    
    }
}
```

DBHelper.java this is where my questions get stored and I have labelled the questions with the qid q1-q5.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1 = new Question("Q1?", "Ans A", "" +
                "Ans B", "Ans C", "Ans A");
        this.addQuestion(q1);

        Question q2 = new Question("Q2?", "Ans A", "" +
                "Ans B", "Ans C", "Ans C");
        this.addQuestion(q2);

        Question q3 = new Question("Q3?", "Ans A", "" +
                "Ans B", "Ans C", "Ans B");
        this.addQuestion(q3);

        Question q4 = new Question("What does q4 do?", "Ans A", "" +
                "Ans B", "Ans C", "Ans C");
        this.addQuestion(q4);

        Question q5 = new Question("What does q5 do?", "Ans A", "" +
                "Ans B", "Ans C", "Ans B");
        this.addQuestion(q5);


    }

    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getAnsA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getAnsB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getAnsC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setAnsA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setAnsB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setAnsC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

I have a Question.java file that contains the basic getters and setters for the questions, ids, answers etc.

Comment: did you add logging to figure out that you're getting what you expect in the switch statement? Because you never gave what Quiz in your switch is, add some logging to confirm what is going on. Never code without logs, that inefficient when it comes to debugging and issue WHILE coding.

Comment: I will try that and I will update the code. Earlier I did try printing a toast with the value in but it kept it at zero, I feel that it may be an error with how the intent is getting retrieved with this line "Quiz = intent.getIntExtra(tutorialpage.Quiz_NUMBER, 0);"

Comment: Dont use toast, use Log for debugging. Will make it much easier and more uniform to debug stuff.